# Not all text shown after selecting from dropdown menu in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm a beginner in Swift, just started learning how to make iOS apps. I'm using Swift 4. I got into a problem while practicing on how to create a dropdown menu, when I select an option from a dropdown menu, not all text of chosen option is shown. 
Please check photos below to get a better idea of what I mean.

[image] 
[image]

As you can see in the second picture, the chosen text is shown like this "Area...umber 1", I want it to show like this "Area Number 1".

Please help and thanks!

Comment: Your label's width might be too small. Make the label wider.

Comment: area number label set the .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true ;

Comment: @mazen Thank you, your solution worked for me :)

Comment: you welcome , but this property will adjusts the font size to fit the label width , so if the text is so long the font size will be too small , so make sure to make the label width to fit the background view width .

Answer (score 0):

You might added constraint for width of label. Please remove it and make it centre horizontal and centre vertical.